# Where did Asimov say this quote, about women becoming lawyers vs doctors or engineers because math was not required?

Tags: quote-source, isaac-asimov

On the [TvTropes page "Everybody Hates Mathematics"](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EverybodyHatesMathematics), in the section of examples from "Real Life", there appears the following excerpt:

> Isaac Asimov once wrote in an editorial that the reason so many women are becoming lawyers — as opposed to doctors, engineers and so on — is that it is the only high-powered profession that requires no mathematics. He was promptly flooded with letters from irate lawyers claiming that they do, too, have to do math: they have to calculate billable hours, and figure taxes, and .... Asimov replied, in effect, "I rest my case". It is very common for people in all walks of life to equate mathematics with arithmetic.

The obvious searches didn't turn up anything, so I'm left wondering if this is made up, or maybe a wrong recollection by an editor of the page.

Comment: Wow. I just lost some of the significant respect I've long held for Asimov. I absolutely **hate** advanced math, yet was a molecular biologist and am a physician, when both were heavily *male-dominated* professions (hint, hint.)  On expressing how disappointed I was on meeting James Watson, a very wise biochemist said, "Yes. Respect for a scientist is often inversely proportional to distance." Once again, it proves true. When their biases are revealed, they're as idiotic as the rest of us.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Asimov indeed wrote this. It's from his editorial "Feminism," published in *Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine*, Mid-December 1988:

> Some time ago, I met a young woman who introduced herself to me as a lawyer. I said, "Yes, everywhere you look you find women becoming lawyers. But do you know why?"
>    Naturally, she said, "Why?"
>    And I said, "Because it's the one profession that requires absolutely no mathematics."

He addressed the replies that he received in the editorial "Wrong!" in *Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine*, September 1989:

> Some wrote to me to denounce me for thinking that women were becoming lawyers because that was one profession that involved no mathematics. Apparently, lawyers *do* have to know mathematics, some who wrote me explained with great indignation, because they had to make out bills and sometimes had to be able to handle compound interest.
>    That's true enough, I suppose. Tellers in banks do that, too, and they're almost all women these days. And there, I admit, I made a mistake.
>    When I talked about mathematics in connection with engineering and science, I suppose I took it for granted that everyone would know that what I meant was calculus and beyond. It didn't occur to me that anyone would think I meant grade-school arithmetic, only.

Comment: Thanks. Here is a link to the Magazines' September edition, in case anyone wants to see it themselves: https://archive.org/details/sim_asimovs-science-fiction_1989-09_13_9

Comment: Out of context, that sounds misogynistic.  Did the context change anything for the better? (*"better"* being non-misogynistic!)

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate: I would say so, and indeed Asimov also felt he needed to clarify his position based on feedback he received for his original "Feminism" editorial: "*There my error might have been that of not making it plain what was bugging me. The thing that bothered me was that women were not* sufficiently *feminist; that they played along with male sexism; that many avoided mathematics because they had somehow allowed themselves to be convinced that their brains weren’t strong enough or bright enough for it;* …"

Comment: … however, Asimov then immediately continues the list with: "*…; that they made use of “makeup” to exaggerate those facets of their appearance designed to advertise their sexuality so as to encourage male advances which they might then claim to be “harassment.”*" So, yeah… one step forward, one step back. :/

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate: Wouldn't suggest reading it as misogynistic.  I mean, there're professions that're more male-dominated and also professions that're more female-dominated -- and presumably no-one's looking down on men for being a minority in female-dominated professions, so why should anyone look down on women for being minority in male-dominated professions?  Though we still might seek to explain why the sexes opt for different professions, and one such reason might be a differing desire to do math all the time.

Comment: @Nat Yes, it's hard to tell.  And that's why context is key.  Was the reason for his comment because he believed that most women *can't* perform advanced mathematics, or simply have a preference (for whatever reason, including societal ones) not to so.  Ilmari's helpful comments regarding the context help illuminate the likelihood that Asimov's comment was the latter.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Thank you for providing context. I appreciate you doing so very much. In your second comment, you mentioned "one step forward, one step back". I think I understand what you are saying (and likely why), but I'm not entirely sure it is one step back.  I'm not saying it isn't... just that I'm not sure.  I work hard to objectively and mindfully see the full equation on that matter, and it is not a simple task.  IOW, I think I see Asimov's point, as well as your point, and I perceive some truth in them both (even if they seem contrary). Again, my sincere thanks for providing context.

Comment: For clarity, I believe all genders are equal, and that sometimes people of different genders use various tactics to attempt to create inequality.  The result is usually, most likely always, not good.

Comment: I seem to remember a collection of essays where he made a statement that sounded vaguely homophobic.  I am not saying he was homophobic but he was very much a product of his era and not necessarily a forward-thinking liberal as sometimes portrayed.

Comment: I'm not aware of anyone claiming Azimov was a "forward-thinking liberal", at least in areas of feminism and the like. He was certainly a product of his time and, in fact, had a well-known reputation as a [serial groper](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/35028/was-isaac-asimov-notorious-for-groping-women).

Comment: @Nat - You must not have experienced (at least) much of medical history. Male nurses used to be rare, and were indeed looked down upon as entering a career beneath them. Female doctors were also relatively rare. I was also asked on all my interviews if I expected to have children, and if so, why a valuable seat in medical school should go to someone who would contribute less to the world of medicine than a male. In my experience (not solely an opinion), many if not most of my early patients believed only a male physician was competent to do such important work. That is discrimination...

Comment: ...and it's backwards. The reason male dominated professions were male dominated (in my own *experience*) is that males wanted it to be that way. Women in science had to hitch their wagons to a powerful male scientist to get grant money (the major reason I left). Do you have any idea of how long it took for women to be accepted into surgical fields? Clearly not. Your opinion is not based in reality, which is a bit harsher than you portray it.